# PHP - strange global behavior

Tags: php, function, include, global-variables

I am trying to access a variable from a function defined in an required file:

```
**main.php**

function run() {
    require('cfg.php');
    require('function.php');
    print(fn());
}


**cfg.php**

$test = 'Var!';


**function.php**

function fn() {
    global $test;
    return $test;
}
```

I expected "Var!" as output. But `$test` seem to be NULL.
I also tried this one for debugging:

```
**function.php

var_dump($test);
function fn() {
    global $test;
    return $test;
}
```

`var_dump()` return the right value... How can I fix this?

Comment: Easy fix: don't use global variables. Pass those variables a parameters instead.

Comment: You're not defining `$test` in `global` __scope__, you're defining it in the __scope__ of the `run()` function, so using `global` is meaningless

Comment: and why does var_dump return 'Var!'?

Comment: Because you're including function.php with that var_dump() within the scope of the `run()` function, and $test is in scope inside that function

Comment: so all in all I could use an anonymous function to success... alright

Answer (score 1):

### Why doesn't it work?

```
function run() {
    require('cfg.php');
    require('function.php');
    print(fn());
}
```

Your code suffers from [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issues. The variables / functions inside `cfg.php` and `function.php` only exist inside the `run()` function and they aren't accessible globally.

Consider your `fn()` function:

```
function fn() {
    global $test;
    return $test;
}
```

You're trying to access `$test` variable. It isn't defined globally, so trying to access it will return `NULL` (as  it should).

Consider the second case:

```
$test = 'Var!';

var_dump($test);

function fn() {
    global $test;
    return $test;
}
```

Here, the `$test` variable *is* defined. So `global $test;` variable will correctly import the variable into the function scope, and the return statement will return the variable. That'd explain why you're getting the output `Var!` for the second code block.

### What should you use instead?

Using `global` variables is not considered good practice as it violates encapsulation etc. I'd recommend not using them.

**Use constants for storing configurations.** The scope of a constant is *global*. You can access constants *anywhere* in your script without regard to scope.

**Separate your logic into multiple files.** Use `cfg.php` for configurations, `functions.php` for functions etc. That way, you can keep your files independently and use one according to the requirements. This way, you can also avoid the headache of having to include from an included file (or even, include from an include from an included file) etc.

---

`config.php`

```
<?php

define('test', 'Var!')
```

`functions.php:`

```
<?php

function doSomething($foo) {
    // do something with $foo and return
}

function somethingElse($bar) {
    // do something with $bar and return
}
```

`main.php:`

```
<?php

require_once 'cfg.php';
require_once 'include.php';

// more code
```

Comment: oh, I've expressed myself wrong, I don't need static variables... the variables contain object, so define would not work for me..

Comment: @IgelHaut: That was just an example. The principle still remains the same. Don't try to cram everything into a function. It's not a good idea.

Comment: the thing is, I intend to write extensible code, with different files and I need sometimes to access the objects in "cfg.php"(in this example). SO now I am thinking about using anonymous functions in the included files

Answer (score 0):

You are including `cfg.php` in the context of your `run` function -- therefore, the variable definition creates a local variable.

You would get the expected behavior if you changed `$test = 'Var!'` to `$GLOBALS['test'] = 'Var!'`, but while that will make the problem go away it's not a good way of doing things -- injecting variables from one script into another scope never is.

What you should probably be doing instead is using [constants](http://www.php.net/constants), e.g.:

```
// cfg.php
const TEST = 'Var!';

// main.php
require('cfg.php');

function run() {
    require('function.php');
    print(fn());
}

// function.php

function fn() {
    return TEST;
}
```

Comment: -1: This is a very bad idea. You'll be `require`ing the file every time the function gets called.

Comment: @AmalMurali: Seeing as this is an abstract example, I don't really agree with this very concrete criticism. How do you know that a function called `run` is going to be called more than once? Would you be satisfied if I changed that to `require_once`?

Comment: I know it's an abstract example and all, but I don't think this is a good practice, @Jon, that's all. And about the function being called multiple times: I don't. That's the point. If I don't know how many times the function is going to get called, why should I allow that possibility? And no, I don't think `require_once()` is the right way to solve this problem :)

Comment: @AmalMurali: `require_once` is not the right way? That's what it's for. How do you know that `function.php` should even be included if `run` is never called?